# How to include bootstrap calendar or any other ui calendar in Angular 2 + Meteor application

Tags: calendar, angular2-forms, angular2-meteor, primeng

What is the right way to include date time picker in Meteor + Angular 2 App
I tried using prime-ng ui calendar

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

error issued - this.calendarElement.datepicker is not a function

If this is the right way of doing the thing or any other more easy way

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what build tool you are using, like SystemJS or Webpack.

You also need to make sure to import all the dependencies mentioned on the documentation: check at the bottom of the page http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

> Dependencies
>
> jQuery UI Datepicker and DateTimePicker

If you are importing all the dependencies, then you need to make sure you are loading them correctly so that they are available to this specific module.

For example if you are using Webpack you should use the ProvidePlugin to make jQuery available to all other modules:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering .. now primeng calendar works great when I am using it in an Angular 2 application but it breaks when using in Meteor + Angular 2 App.. Also I dont think we are using SystemJS or Webpack in case on Meteor It uses browsify to load modules